# Customize swagger page to include schema section within endpoint section in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetcore - 6.5 version.

In the Swagger page, is there any way in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API to include schema section inside endpoint section itself?

[image] ??

Comment: [Isn't it also included by default?](https://i.imgur.com/hHk3QSh.png)

Comment: Yes, it's included but as separate section under Schemas. Is there any way we can include with in endpoint section itself??